# I can't find selectSingleNode method in my xml dom - metro style

Tags: xml, microsoft-metro, selectsinglenode, winjs

I want to write a RSS reader in metro style, below is one of functions in my app.

```
function btnOKClick() {
        var btnOK = document.getElementById("btnOK");
        var txtAddress = document.getElementById("rssAddress");
        WinJS.xhr({ url: txtAddress.value }).done(function (result) {
            var xml = result.responseXML;
            //xml.selectSingleNode();
    });
```

But I can't find selectSingleNode method in my xml variable. Any one can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the `selectSingleNode` method was available up through the Consumer Preview release but was removed in later builds because, as [Kraig Brockschmidt puts it](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithhtml5/thread/2141429b-b7d3-46ef-a46b-5919e41d454f/):

> ...the underlying object type of the
>   `request.responseXML` was changed, and that object has its own API. 
>   Before it was an XML DOM object (out of the MSXML library), but it was
>   changed to an HTML DOM object, hence the change in methods and
>   properties.

[In the same post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithhtml5/thread/2141429b-b7d3-46ef-a46b-5919e41d454f/), Kraig gives the new alternative to `selectSingleNode`:

> you need to use `querySelector` instead of `selectNodes`...It 
>   should be now something like:
>
> `var categories = request.responseXML.querySelectorAll("entry");`